# Backreferences evaluation time in gsub

Tags: r, evaluation, gsub

I am trying to generate functions combining n gaussians, and using values retrieved from a `nls` run. I use `gsub` to replace the original coefficients with the `nls` ones using backreferences. However, it seems that `[` on the datafame evaluates before the `\\1`.

Here is a MWE :

```
nls <- data.frame(Estimate = seq(1,3))
row.names(nls) <- c("a","b","c")
gsub("(a|b|c)",paste0(" ",nls["\\1","Estimate"]," "),"a + b*x + c*x^2")
```

As you can see, the replacements are NAs, while the call to the nls dataframe appear to be valid :

```
gsub("(a|b|c)",paste0(" ","\\1","Estimate"," "),"a + b*x + c*x^2")
```

Any ideas to delay the evaluation of `[` ?

Thanks !

EDIT : for the sake of clarity, here is the full function now working great (it takes number of peaks, formula of one peak, parameters in the formula, variable, constant boolean, and nls results as arguments, and returns the formula for use in `ggplot`'s `stat_function()` :

```
Generate_func <- function(peakNb,peakForm,peakParams, peakVar, constBool,nls){
  res <- as.data.frame(summary(nls)$coefficients, optional = T)
  rhs <- strsplit(peakForm, "~")[[1]][[2]]
  regex <- paste0("([*+-/\\^\\(\\)[:space:]]|^)(",paste0(peakParams, collapse = "|"),")([*+-/\\^\\(\\)[:space:]]|$)")
  exp_names <- paste0(sapply(seq(1,peakNb),function(i){
    paste0(sapply(peakParams, function(j){
      paste0(j,i)
    }))
  }))
  if(constBool){exp_names <- c("C", exp_names)}
  func_text <- paste0(sapply(seq(1,peakNb),function(n){gsubfn(regex, x + y + z ~ paste0(x,res[paste0(y,n),"Estimate"],z), rhs )}), collapse = " + ")
  func_text <- paste0(ifelse(constBool,paste0(res["C","Estimate"]," + "),""), func_text)

  func <- function(x){
    eval(parse(text = func_text))
  }
  names(formals(func)) <- c(peakVar)

  print(func_text)

  func
}
```

And here is an usage example (nls data not included for length sake):

```
> testfunc <- Generate_func(3, "intensity_cnt ~ a * exp((-(energy_eV-b)^2)/(2*c^2))", c("a","b","c"), "energy_eV", constBool = T, testnls)
[1] "1000 +  32327.6598743022 * exp((-(energy_eV-1.44676439236578)^2)/(2*0.0349194350021539^2)) +  10000 * exp((-(energy_eV-1.49449385009962)^2)/(2*0.0102269096492807^2)) +  54941.8293572164 * exp((-(energy_eV-1.5321664735001)^2)/(2*0.01763494864617^2))"
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** `gsub` replaces a pattern with a constant but what you are looking to do is to replace it with the result of applying a function to the matched string.  `gusbfn` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) does that.  Below, the formula in the second argument is just gsubfn's short form for a function whose argument is the left hand side and the body is the right hand side.  Alternately the second argument could be expressed in the usual function notation ( `function(x) nls[x,]` ) but at the expense of a bit of verbosity:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> gsubfn("a|b|c", x ~ nls[x, ], "a + b*x + c*x^2")
[1] "1 + 2*x + 3*x^2"
```

Note that `"a|b|c"` could be derived from `nls` using `paste(rownames(nls), collapse = "|")` in order to avoid redundant specification.

**2)** Although `gsubfn` simplifies this significantly, to do it without `gsubfn` use `substitute` :

```
> L <- as.list(setNames(nls[[1]], rownames(nls)))  # L <- list(a = 1L, b = 2L, c = 3L)
> e <- parse(text = "a + b * x + c * x ^ 2")[[1]]  # e is the text as a "call" object
> s <- do.call(substitute, list(e, L))             # perform the substitution
> format(s)                                        # convert to character
[1] "1L + 2L * x + 3L * x^2"
```

The `L`s are due to the fact that `nls` as defined in the question contains integers. Convert them to numeric before running the above if you don't like that:

```
nls[[1]] <- as.numeric(nls[[1]])
```

**3)**  Another possibility is to loop over the strings to be substituted.

```
> s <- "a + b*x + c*x^2"
> for(nm in rownames(nls)) s <- gsub(nm, nls[nm, ], s)
> s
[1] "1 + 2*x + 3*x^2"
```

If we knew there was no more than one occurrence of each to be replaced we could use `sub` in place of `gsub` here.

UPDATE: Corrected second solution.

UPDATE 2: Added third solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, I cannot use the second proposal since my original issue is a bit more complex though. I will accept your answer after more extensive tests on the full issue (tomorrow). Thanks again !

Comment: I have updated the code to compute `L` to show how it can be derived from `nls`.

Comment: And have further updated to show how to do it if the quadratic is expressed as a string.

Comment: I really need to thank you ! The first solution works like a charm in my complicated case. I added the full function to show why other options could not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it

```
gsub(paste0(row.names(nls), "(.*)", collapse=""),  paste0(t(nls),  paste0("\\", 1:nrow(nls)), collapse=""), "a + b*x + c*x^2"  )
[1] "1 + 2*x + 3*x^2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but the `gsubfn` solution is better suited to my particular issue.